# MySQL PHPMyAdmin stored procedure won't return multiple rows

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures, phpmyadmin

I am simply testing a stored procedure:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE sp_test()
BEGIN
  select * from users;
END
```

Which should return 3 rows. However, when calling

```
call sp_test()
```

There is no result at all:

[image]

This process is SSMS would result in the result set. Is there a configuration that must be set in PHPMyAdmin to allow for returning multiple rows?

Answer (score 0):

What version of phpMyAdmin are you using?

I just downloaded XAMPP 5.5.19 and 5.6.3 and both use phpMyAdmin Version 4.2.11. I noted a lot of bugs so I reverted to my older XAMPP v3.2.1 which has phpMyAdmin Version 4.0.4.1

You could resort to the MySQL shell and that should work correctly.